# Duplicate a row in a specific position

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

With a grid, I want to duplicate a row selected.

Then I want to insert a copy of the row in the grid position immediately following the row selected.

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hc6

```
var grid = this.up('grid');
var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].copy(null);

var store = grid.getStore();
var row = store.indexOf(record);

store.insert(row, record); //store.insert(row + 1, record);?????
```

**I EDITED fiddle with solution**

Comment: You're trying to get the indexOf the copied record. Get the index of the record, then copy it.

Comment: Thanks Evan. It was this detail that was causing the problem. Now it works properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is down to variable naming. Your variable called `record` is in fact the copy. Hence when you search record against the store, your row index variable returned index -1 and hence was inserted at the end (probably default behavior of the store API).

The below changes will get what you want:

```
var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
var copy = record.copy(null);
...
var row = store.indexOf(record); // this used to be -1
store.insert(row, copy);
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson, Evan had called me to attention to this detail.
Thanks for helping with the code and explanation.